# Angular mat card won't wrap ngx-charts element

Tags: css, angular-material, ngx-charts

I am trying to put ngx-charts elements into mat-cards in Angular.
But `<mat-card>` will not encapsulate the graphic. I have found the exact same issue [here](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts/issues/1182), and yet, the solution does not seem to work for me.

[image: not wrapping]

My html looks like this:

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Starting fifteen</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

        <ngx-charts-pie-chart 
            [results]="starting"
            [legend]="false"
            [doughnut]="true"
            [view]="[100,100]"
            [labels]="false" >
        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
                
   
</mat-card>
```

The solution suggests wrapping the `<ngx-charts-pie-chart>` in a `<div class="spectre-pie-chart">` and applying the following style to it:

```css
:host {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.spectre-pie-chart {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
}
```

I think I might have applied the `sccs` to a wrong element. The solution is not overly particular on how to apply it. Can anybody help me getting the card to fully wrap around the graphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="chart-container">
    <div class="spectre-pie-chart">
         <ngx-charts-pie-chart 
            [results]="starting"
            [legend]="false"
            [doughnut]="true"
            [view]="[100,100]"
            [labels]="false" >
        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
    </div>
</div>
```

You should add your chart inside a parent container, it should fix your problem

Comment: That, I get, but what I don't get is, what element to add the `:host` css to. Is this a global option? Because it doesn't seem to work if I just copy this into the components scss file.

Comment: Yep you're right. I find a solution. Add this class to your mat-card                                                       
 .fix-bug-class {
  display: flex !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}

Comment: I tested it and it works fine, i hope you won't get problems